# apache24 overriding AuthName in htaccess doesn't work

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

Trying to use `AuthName` in a .htaccess file to override the top-level config setting doesn't work - the server still sends the value for `WWW-Authenticate:"Basic realm="...""` that's set in the config. This is despite having `AllowOverride AuthConfig` enabled. Am I doing something wrong, or did I find a bug?

httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "/www">
  AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

<Location />
  AuthName "config"
</Location>
```

/www/.htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "htaccess"
AuthUserFile /dev/null
Require user nobody
```

PS: The real-world version of the above example is having a common top-level 'single sign-on' auth setup, and then just putting the single line "Require valid-user" and such in htaccess files. The conflict happened with a subdirectory that uses a fake auth realm to implement logout for basic auth.

Comment: Location is a tad different context,  it is used for virtual paths, while your .htaccess is meant for directory configuration override, move the AuthName to directory and see if it still not getting overriden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ezra-s suggested in comments, you need to move the `AuthName` directive out of the `<Location>` container and set in the `<Directory>` container.

`<Location>` containers are processed much later in the request, after `<Directory>` containers and `.htaccess` files. So this will be overriding your `.htaccess` file.

Also, you shouldn't use `<Location>` containers when dealing with authentication for parts of the filesystem, as they can be circumvented if resources are accessed from multiple URLs.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of the ordering issue. I avoid Directory because it requires absolute filesystem paths, and normally their definitions don't try to override each other. Could you please clarify that "Also, ... circumvented" sentence?

Comment: You can use wildcards and regex in `<Directory>` and `<DirectoryMatch>` containers if that will help. But note that if regex are used then these are processed _after_ non-regex versions. It's possible that you might have different URLs that map to the same resource of the filesystem. If your www-authentication is based on one URL (ie. `<Location>`) and the other URL is accessed then your authentication is bypassed/circumvented.

Comment: ...that's when dealing with authentication of parts of the "filesystem".